# Error: org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: EmpClass

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

When i'm trying to run the test suite, am getting this exception. We are using maven project here and i am done with refreshing, cleaning, reinstalling testNG and then imported the maven projects but then also am getting the same exception. Please suggest any ways that am missing here.

Error console:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: EmpClass

at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1350)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2778)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Tell us how did you configure your test cases. We can't help by just looking at exception stacktrace....

Comment: I configure test cases by taking the help of this link   http://selftechy.com/2012/01/09/setting-up-testng-with-eclipse

Comment: 1) I create a new java project  2) Downloaded the TestNG archive (testng-6.8.jar file)  3) Configure the build path for testng-6.8.jar

Comment: If you're using Maven, why don't you include TestNG on your Maven POM and with a `test` scope? From there, add your test classes in your `src/test` folder?

Comment: For me, this problem turned out to be a problem with not using the standard directory layout, so maven wasn't seeing the needed java file when it compiled.

Comment: Sometimes I had the same issue try with "Install jars bson, Compress extend, freemarker, reactive streams, rxjava, sparkcore, testng"

Answer (score 24):

I also got the same exception:

I tried the following steps:

1. In Eclipse> Project > Clean. (The Exception remained)
2. I ran another project(The testng.xml ran successfully)

After running another project, I ran the project in which I was getting the Exception, and fortunately it worked for me, with no errors.

Comment: Was facing Same error. Cleaning the project worked for me.

Comment: After every run of TestNG test, I had to do a mvn clean install and then re-run the test. Otherwise, the error persists.

Comment: In Intellij IDE - File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart

Comment: 2022, it still works. I just rebuild mvn project by navigating Build > Rebuild project

Answer (score 15):

You have to edit your tests Runner xml file.
See this example:

```
 <test name="Employees Test">
               <classes>
                      <class name="packagename.classname">
                       </class>
               </classes>
 </test>
```

In `<class name="packagename.classname">` row you must enter your tests package name then name of class that you want to run.

Thanks and wish you all the best.

Comment: It does not work for me at all. And hasn't any sense, too - if it can't find TestNGException file, how can help exact pointing to test classes?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my IntelliJ cannot find the TestNGException itself... Then you have only one problem in your explanations: You cannot point to classes and packages in one test description, it is shown as an error. Your example is OK.

Comment: Cool, Good luck :)

Comment: I was facing the same error and it helped!. Thanks, pal :)

Answer (score 14):

I faced the similar issue on importing maven with testng project. This was solved by converting again into TestNg project by

> right click on eclipse project > TestNG > Convert to TestNG

and replacing the existing `testng.xml` file with the newly created. Clean and update the maven project with `mvn install`

Note: take backup of your `testng.xml`

Answer (score 9):

Project>>Clean and Maven>>Update Project worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Go to 
Project>Build Path>Configure Build Path>Libraries>Remove Error libraries

After Refresh project and run again program.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents on the problem: I was experiencing the same problem, while some part of my path was in Cyrillic. So check the path to your project for special characters. Once I removed this, the problem was fixed

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I cleaned the maven project then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem with TestNG version 6.14.2

However, this was due to a foolish mistake on my end and there is no issue whatsoever with maven, testng or eclipse. What I was doing was -

1. Run project as "mvn clean"
2. Select "testng.xml" file and right click on it to run as TestNG suite
3. This was giving me the same error as reported in the original question
4. I soon realized that I have not compiled the project and the required class files have not been generated that the TestNG would utilize subsequently
5. The "target" folder will be generated only after the project is compiled (Run as "mvn build")
6. If your project is compiled, this issue should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i was using selenium 3.11.xx dependency however my problem was resolved when i used selenium 3.4.x dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, try the following:

1. From 'File', select "Invalidate Caches/ Restart" option.
2. Confirm this action by clicking the "Invalidate and Restart" button.
3. Then the IDEA will be restarted.
4. You will then find a fresh copy of your project.
5. You then need to import/ change project format to the Maven project. IDEA will show you options at the bottom right corner.
6. After this, you should be able to run your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and the project had some build errors.
I did sudo -R 777 to the project and then I cleaned my project.
After that it worked fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when tried to run my tests in a JSF project.

I´m using Eclipse IDE (kepler). So, I did "project > clean" and then ran the tests again of the same project.

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Note: You have to specify class name along with packages as given below.

```
<suite name="testNGLearning">
    <test name="simpleTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="testngTests.TestNGSimpleTest" />
            <class name="testngTests.TestMessageUtil" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the IDE working again. The solution is quite funny - and even a re-install, and deleting the IDE does not fix it on windows. What you need to do in that case, is to go to the testNG run configurations - and delete them all. 
This is for the TestNG XML classpath error on windows OS. I am using spring tools suite 3.6.4.

Make certain that you delete all the configurations, make sure the project can build, and if there are no problems, the test should run now.

Regards
-Anthony Toorie

Answer (score 0):

In testng.xml file, remove "." from tag "" class name if you are not using packages.

Answer (score 0):

include the package name with class. It will remove your name. I also got the same issue but adding the package name with class fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was very strange.
I have a testng.xml file at the root of my Eclipse project.  When I changed the file through Eclipse, it wasn't changing the testng.xml file in my directory.

Turns out it made a copy of the folder into the eclipse workspace..

Hope this helps someone out

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if src has test/java/ folders then in build path out location should be like target/test-classes.

If src has main/java/ folders then in build path out location should be like target/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue stated above today. **setting the class-path again in eclipse ** solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems with this until recently.

Now I had to **move the suite's xml test file into the root of the project I was testing.**

It may be that there is a setting to point at the classes I am testing, but I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was because I excluded the test from compilation in the POM. My pom.xml looked like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <testExcludes>
            <exclude>com/mycompany/app/AppTest.java</exclude>
        </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After removing the `<exclude>`, I was able to run the tests in `AppTest.java` again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I imported maven project as Default existing project in eclipse.After that I imported as maven project.That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by adding TestNG.class package to OnlineStore package as below

1. Step 1: Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path > Select
   "Project" tab
2. Step 2: Click "add" button and select the project with contains the
   TestNG source.
3. Step 3 select TestNG.xml run as "TestNG Suite"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I imported my project from one PC to another on IntelliJ IDEA.

Below Solution worked for me:

1. Import project using Git.
2. After Importing IDE would prompt you a dialog on the bottom right corner saying "Import as Gradle", you need to select that but make Sure you have set JAVA_HOME and GRADLE(Gradle Home or Gradle wrapper both should work) properly.
3. Run the build.gradle and make sure all the dependencies are downloaded correctly without any error.
4. Now move to your Test Case and try to run with TestNG or JUnit and if you have followed above 3 steps properly you should able to run the test case.

Answer (score 0):

After done trying everything that I found on this issue, in eclipse,

I selected my project --> right click --> Run as --> Maven generate-sources

[image]

Then I re-ran my TestNG project and it ran perfectly fine without any issues.Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I added **Skip Tests** checkbox/flag in the Maven Build of the Project

Therefore the test classes **weren't compiled** and then weren't found by TestNG

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.
I was using `src/main/java` for configuration files and `src/test/java` for test files. 
Because of this testNG couldn't find the class path. 
To prevent getting that error need to move all the files from `src/main/java` to `src/test/java` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should create **package** first and then create new TestNG class under that package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class is under src.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share what worked for me:

1. When we do "mvn clean"  - we are cleaning old compiled classes
   please lgo to ocation "your project directroy -> target " you will find this folder is getting cleaned because that's where MVN places it's compiled artifacts
2. Since it's already a MAVEN project then go to your project folder and open in command prompt. And issue "mvn clean" and then "mvn test"
   -> "mvn test" command will place all the compiled files under proper folders and then you can run your tests through TestNG or MAVEN itself.
3. Make sure you set up "M2_HOME" or "MAVEN_HOME" to your env path , sometime 
   "MAVEN_HOME" doesn't work so add "M2_HOME" as well (google it for this set up)

Above suggestions worked for me so I wanted to share, good luck

Answer (score 0):

It happens when MAVEN is not installed locally on the system.

I faced the same issue when i cloned a Maven based Project from GIT and then as soon as I executed I got exception "Cannot Find Class In ClassPath : Class Name"

So i did a **mvn clean test** and found that maven is not installed locally.

After doing **sudo apt install maven** Maven got installed and i was able to Run the code

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when listener  was under src/main/java folder and the base class was under src/test/java, I moved base class under src/main/java  and it worked perfectly well [image]l

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. In my case it was caused by an abstract test class in a separate `test` package from which all my NG tests were derived. Once I moved that abstract class to the root of the test package, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Maven project in Eclipse, the following steps will fix your issue.

1. Right-click on the Project folder(Workplace)
2. Follow this path and select the **Update project** option

[image]