# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: com.test.zhihu.test1

Tags: testng, appium

I have a java + appium project, but when I run it, it throws an error,

1. I have tried `Project->Clean` and run again, but it didn't work for me.
2. I also tried checking the **`testng.xml`**, but nothing is wrong.

Error Trace:

```
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.j    ava:543)
at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.initialize(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:136)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Can you show us how your project structure looks like along with the complete testng suite contents ? The problem is rather straight forward, the fully qualified package name of your class cannot be found by TestNG, but the cause of that can be ascertained only if you add more context. Please edit your question and add more context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543910/error-org-testng-testngexception-cannot-find-class-in-classpath-empclass